# C++ custom string class implementation

Tags: c++, strings, reinventing-the-wheel, c++17

I recently had an interview where I was tasked with implementing a custom C++ string class without using the STL. The interviewer provided the function signatures and variable declarations, specifying that the APIs and parameters were fixed and could not be altered. My responsibility was to complete the function implementations within these constraints. I would greatly appreciate any advice or constructive criticism on my implementation.

```
class String {
public:
    String() : data(new char[1]{'\0'}), size(0) {}
    
    String(const char* str);
    String(const String& other);
    String(String&& other) noexcept;
    
    ~String();
    
    String& operator=(const String& other);
    String& operator=(String&& other) noexcept;
    
    String operator+(const String& other);
    String& operator+=(const String& other);
    
    char& operator[](std::size_t index);
    const char& operator[](std::size_t index) const;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const String& str);

private:
    char* data;
    std::size_t size;
};

String::String(const char* str) {
    if (str) {
        size = std::strlen(str);
        data = new char[size + 1];
        std::strcpy(data, str);
    } else {
        data = new char[1];
        data[0] = '\0';
        size = 0;
    }
}

String::String(const String& other) {
    size = other.size;
    data = new char[size + 1];
    std::strcpy(data, other.data);
}

String::String(String&& other) noexcept : data(other.data), size(other.size) {
    other.data = nullptr;
    other.size = 0;
}

String::~String() {
    delete[] data;
}

String& String::operator=(const String& other) {
    if (this == &other) {
        return *this;
    }
    
    delete[] data;
    
    size = other.size;
    data = new char[size + 1];
    std::strcpy(data, other.data);
    
    return *this;
}

String& String::operator=(String&& other) noexcept {
    if (this == &other) {
        return *this;
    }

    delete[] data;
    
    data = other.data;
    size = other.size;

    other.data = nullptr;
    other.size = 0;
    
    return *this;
}

String String::operator+(const String& other) {
    String newStr;
    newStr.size = size + other.size;
    newStr.data = new char[newStr.size + 1];
    
    std::strcpy(newStr.data, data);
    std::strcat(newStr.data, other.data);
    
    return newStr;
}

String& String::operator+=(const String& other) {
    char* newData = new char[size + other.size + 1];
    std::strcpy(newData, data);
    std::strcat(newData, other.data);
    
    delete[] data;
    data = newData;
    size += other.size;
    
    return *this;
}

char& String::operator[](std::size_t index) {
    if (index >= size) {
        throw std::out_of_range("Index out of range");
    }
    return data[index];
}

const char& String::operator[](std::size_t index) const {
    if (index >= size) {
        throw std::out_of_range("Index out of range");
    }
    return data[index];
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const String& str) {
    os << str.data;
    return os;
}
```

Comment: Looks promising, yet how about adding a method returning the length of the string?

Comment: Consider using small string optimization to impress the interviewer. The standard also allocates memory in multiples of two. This has a benefit of making concatination less prone to mallocs.

Answer (score 6):

This looks quite good, I see you have thought about most of the corner cases. However, a few were missed:

## `new` can throw

When you allocate memory with `new`, an exception can be thrown if the system is out of memory. In some cases it's fine to not handle this and let this propagate to the caller, but you should only do that if you left your object in a valid state. Consider these lines from the copy assignment operator:

```
delete[] data;
size = other.size;
data = new char[size + 1]; // could throw!
```

If the last line throws an exception, then you have already deleted `data`, but `size` is set to `other.size`. This leaves your `String` object in an invalid state, since you assume that, apart from right after moves, `data` is always a non-null pointer. So calling `operator[]()` will now crash with a segmentation fault due to a null-pointer dereference.

Make sure you handle this case correctly. Ideally, the state of the object is unchanged if an exception is thrown in any operation. So call `new` *first*, store the result in a temporary pointer, copy the data over, and only then replace `data` with the pointer to the new storage, and delete the old data.

## In C++, strings can contain NUL-bytes

Contrary to C-strings, where a NUL-byte signifies the end of the string, in C++ a `std::string` can contain as many NUL-bytes as you want. But the C functions `strcpy()` and `strcat()` don't know about that, so this could result in less data being copied than needed. You can in fact create such a string by doing:

```
String hello("Hello, world!");
hello[5] = '\0';
```

## Memory leak in `operator+()`

In `operator+()` you default-construct `newStr`. This causes it to allocate one byte. However, you then allocate a new array and assign it to `newStr.data` without deleting that one byte first.

## Performance

Apart from the above correctness issues, there might be some ways to improve performance. First, instead of unconditionally `delete[]`ing old storage in the assignment operator, consider that you can check if the old storage is big enough to hold the new string. In that case, you don't have to do a new allocation.

Second, it is common in the standard library that `operator[]` does not do range checks, if you want those you can use the [`at()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/at) member function. However, if they have given you the function prototypes and added `noexcept` to the move constructor/assignment operator but not to `operator[]()`, then maybe they did intend for you to do the range check.

An empty string optimization could have been done, where you don't allocate memory in the default constructor. You would need to add some checks here and there to handle this, but it would have avoided the unnecessary allocation in `operator+()` for `newStr`.

Comment: As to the NULL-bytes in C++ string, do I need to use memcpy instead of strcpy? @G. Sliepen

Comment: Yes. Or even better, the C++ equivalent: [`std::copy_n()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy_n).

Comment: Get used to not using **mem** functions. All have better generic alternatives in `std`.

Answer (score 4):

#### You Can Add `private` Member Functions and `friend` Functions

At least, I think you can.  That doesn’t change the the public API one whit, or the ABI (so long as none of them are `virtual`) so it ought to be kosher.  I would start with `constexpr String::swap(String& other) noexcept` and `constexpr String::String(char* const moved_data, const std::size_t other_size) noexcept`.

The value of the `swap` is that it lets you use the copy-and-swap idiom, which solves many of your exception-safety bugs.  This also makes it much easier to write a lock-free, thread-safe implementation.

The value of a `private:` constructor that sets `data` and `size` is that you frequently default-initialize a `String` object, which allocates one byte of memory, and then never `delete[]` its memory.  You could insert a call to `newstr::~String();` between the declaration and the initialization each and every time, but it would be much better to be able to just write:

```
String newstr(new_data, new_size);
```

#### Use the Correct String-Copy Functions

G. Sleipen already brought up that C++ strings can contain `'\0'` bytes.  They didn’t mention that there are several different places where this causes a bug, such as:

```
String::String(const String& other) {
    size = other.size;
    data = new char[size + 1];
    std::strcpy(data, other.data);
}
```

This will fail to copy any data after a `\0`.  Everywhere you use `std::strcpy` in this code, you should be using `std::memcpy`.  This also will have the advantage of being faster.

#### Prefer Member-Initializer Lists in your Constructors

Code such as

```
constexpr String(char* const moved_data, const std::size new_size) noexcept
 : data(moved_data), size(new_size)
{}
```

makes it easy to verify that each data member is initialized once and only once.  Compilers are very good at optimizing constructors that have this form.  It’s also, in my opinion, elegant.  (The one gotcha is that the data members will be set in the order that they are declared within your class definition, not the order in which you write the commands.)

In some cases, this form of initialization would force you to write a helper (or “phi”) function, such as

```
String::String(const String& other)
 : data(new_copy(other.data, other.size)), size(other.size)
{}
```

If `new_copy` is a useful function that you will re-use in several places and simplify your implementations, this is a big win.

#### Use Your Functions to Implement Each Other

The interviewer is testing you to see if you implement operators like `=` and `+` by delegating to simpler building blocks, such as the copy constructor.

Comment: @G.Sliepen Good point; I meant `memcpy()`. Will fix.

Comment: Instead of `std::memcpy` you should recommend `std::copy` or `std::copy_n`.

Answer (score 3):

#### Overview:

I found one bug.
Your move constructor puts the object into an invalid state, where you can then potentially invoke undefined behavior.

You have a small memory leak in the `operator+`.

Couple of places where you are using non-standard techniques.

1. Check for self assignment.
2. Not using copy and swap
3. Missing swap method
4. Not using initializer lists.

None of it terribly bad. But as a result makes your code longer and thus harder to parse.

Other people have mentioned that you can't assume that a string does not include a null character. So using the C libraries strcpy() and strcat() are not safe. Prefer to use `std::copy()`.

Also using throwing operation when you have put the object into an invalid state is not safe.

Standard technique is:

1. Do all throwing operations first
2. Modify state with only non throwing operations.
3. Release any resources.

#### Code Review:

Don't see why you need special code here. Use the ability to chain constructors to simplify this and make sure that you have one place that does the allocation:

```
    String() : data(new char[1]{'\0'}), size(0) {}
```

I would write like this:

```
    String()
        : String("").     // or even nullptr are you support the check
                          // for null in that constructor.
    {}
```

---

Why only output?

```
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const String& str);
```

Normally you want to support both input and output!

---

Sure. That will work.

```
    char* data;
    std::size_t size;
```

But any change in size is now going to result in a resize.
Might be nice to be able to remove then add data without reallocating memory all the time.

Note: I say might. You will have to look at the use of your `String` and see if that is worth the extra variable.

---

I always prefer to use the initializer list to initialize the variables.

```
String::String(const char* str) {
    if (str) {
        size = std::strlen(str);
        data = new char[size + 1];
        std::strcpy(data, str);
    } else {
        data = new char[1];
        data[0] = '\0';
        size = 0;
    }
}
```

I would write like this:

```
String::String(char const* str)
    : size(str ? strlen(str), 0)
    , data(new char[size + 1])
    // Note you will need to swap the order of the member
    // variables
{
    std::copy(str, str + size, data);
    data[size] = '\0';
}
```

---

Again I prefer to always use the initializer list.

```
String::String(const String& other) {
    size = other.size;
    data = new char[size + 1];
    std::strcpy(data, other.data);
}
```

SO I would write like this:

```
String::String(const String& other)
    : size(other.size)
    , data(new char[size + 1])
{
    std::copy(other.data, other.data + size + 1, data);
}
```

---

You can write this simpler using `std::exchange`.

```
String::String(String&& other) noexcept : data(other.data), size(other.size) {
    other.data = nullptr;
    other.size = 0;
}
```

Write like this:

```
String::String(String&& other) noexcept
    : size(std::exchange(other.size, 0))
    , data(std::exchange(other.data, nullptr))
{}
```

I would point out that you just put the `other` object into a state that has a `nullptr`. This is not done in any of your constructors. I would assume that this is not a valid state for a normal object. This looks like a bug to me!

If I did this:

```
String   one("One");
String   sizeOne = std::move(One);

char last = one[0];  // Would you expect that to crash?
```

---

I would consider this bad practice:

```
    if (this == &other) {
        return *this;
    }
```

Yes; you do have to write in a way that works for self assignment. But this is self pessimizing code. The case that practically never happens is probably going to cost extra.

The standard technique has been, for many years now, a technique called copy and swap. This does not use a test for self assignment.

---

There is a standard technique for writing the copy and move assignment operator as a single function.

```
String& String::operator=(const String& other) {
   
    if (this == &other) {
        return *this;
    }
    
    delete[] data;
    
    size = other.size;
    data = new char[size + 1];       // Throwing operation.
                                     // done after modifying state.
                                     // object not in a consistent state.

    std::strcpy(data, other.data);
    
    return *this;
}

String& String::operator=(String&& other) noexcept {
    if (this == &other) {
        return *this;
    }

    delete[] data;                   // Not an issue with char
                                     // But you can't assume that
                                     // delete is always safe to call (think about this situation if you were building a vector rather than string).
    
    data = other.data;
    size = other.size;

    other.data = nullptr;
    other.size = 0;
    
    return *this;
}
```

I would write like this (supports copy and move)

```
// Notice parameter is passed by value.
//    L-Value input is copied.
//    R-Value input is moved.
String& String::operator=(String other) noexcept
{
    swap(other);
    return *this;
}
```

Note: If you use assignment with an L-Value it is copied into the parameter `other` then state is swapped. This is the same cost as you have above. If you do assignment with R-Value then it is moved into the parameter (no copy) then state is swapped. This is the same cost as you have above. You do have to write `swap()` but that is relatively trivial.

---

It is common to write `operator+` in terms of `operator+=`:

```
String String::operator+(const String& other) {
    String newStr;                            // Note this allocated memory.
                                              // You are overwritting "data"
                                              // Without releasing this memory.
                                              // So you have a memory leak.

    newStr.size = size + other.size;
    newStr.data = new char[newStr.size + 1];
    
    std::strcpy(newStr.data, data);
    std::strcat(newStr.data, other.data);
    
    return newStr;
}
```

I would simplify this to:

```
String String::operator+(const String& other)
{
    // Note: Your class is not implemented in a way
    //       That makes this efficient. But with a tiny bit of work.
    //       This can be made to be just as efficient.
    String result(*this);
    return result += other;
}
```

---

In `std::string` the `operator[]` is not checked. It is assumed you have pre-checked. This is to optimize for speed. The `std::string` has a seprate method that has a checked bounds check `at()`.

```
char& String::operator[](std::size_t index) {
    if (index >= size) {
        throw std::out_of_range("Index out of range");
    }
    return data[index];
}
```

Consider the following:

1: You update your code to support either `size()` or `begin()` and `end()`. In this case you can loop over the code:

```
for (int loop = 0; loop < string.size(); ++loop) {
    std::cout << string[loop] << "n";
}
```

Here we know that `loop` is always inside the correct bounds and will never throw. So why am I paying the price of checking the loop bounds on every access to `operator[]` when I have already guaranteed that accesses will be within bounds.

---

Lets simplify this to a single line:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const String& str) {
    // Note: You are ssuming that there are no null characters in this string.
    os << str.data;
    return os;
}
```

I would write like this:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, String const& str) {
    return os << std::string_view(str.data, str.size);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The interface of your class is fine: you are following the **rule 5**; that means you have the 5 big special functions:

1. Destructor
2. Copy constructor
3. Copy assignment operator
4. Move constructor
5. Move assignment operator

The general rule of thumb is **rule 035**: either define none of the above, or define the 1st 3, or define all 5. In corner cases you can define #1 and either/both of #4 or/and #5, where the compiler implicitly sets #2 and #3 to `=delete`.
If you diviate from **rule 035**, then your code eventually hits one of the major bugs:

1. Resource/memory leak
2. Double delete
3. Use after free

Now **rule 5** which you have chosen is about performance optimization. If you just wanted correctness, you could stick to **rule 3** and implement it with **copy/swap idiom**. Since you have chosen to have a performance optimized string class, you should have considered removing excessive alloc/dealloc in your assignment operators:

1. You should've introduced a private `capacity` member to store current available bytes and assert that always `capacity>=size`.
2. When assigning(in both add & copy), if the destination capacity is larger than source size, you can skip alloc/dealloc and copy bytes, followed by `std::fill_n` to zero.
3. In move assignment, you can select between source and destination buffer to keep, based on capacities: either swap buffer pointers, or `std::copy_n` destination from source.

Finally since you want to keep things simple, and custom allocations are not part of the picture, you can avoid `new/delete` and use `std::free` for deallocation. C function `strdup` creates a duplicate of its operand in ram and returns the start address. The safer C function `strndup` takes a maximum byte count as its second argument. Both of them are C API functions; they don't `throw` and their results can be checked against `nullptr`.
I would also go ahead and define a char array accepting constructor too:

```
template<std::size_t N>
String::String(char const (&arr)[N]);
//I skipped the definition
```

This constructor prevents string literals inputs from decaying to pointers; it grabs them by reference and has to duplicate them(like the char pointer overload), but gets the size information instantly from `N`: if last character is not null `N + 1`, other was just `N`. I would also mark the pointer overload as `explicit` and give it a defaulted `count` argument:

```
explicit String::String(char const* begin, std::size_t count = ~0ull);
//I skipped the definition
```

Now I have a more generic constructor that deals with char arrays created at runtime(literal strings are copied via the template constructor above).

Sorry for lack of code snippets; This is not about reviewing my implementation after all.

==================================

**To anyone reading this:**

I made a terrible mistake of introducing `strdup` and `strndup` as `std` C++ functions; they seem to be not. But I like them. If you plan on to work on POSIX compliant systems, they can be good choices.

Comment: When did `std::strdup()` and `std::strndup()` get added to C++?  I thought those were C only, so far (added in C23).  Certainly the [latest draft standard](https://eel.is/c++draft/cstring.syn) doesn't mention either function.

Comment: @TobySpeight fair point. I have seen and used `strdup` long ago. It stroke me to find their not std. Thank you. I have to edit the post sometime later.